# RegularExpression no longer working in Mathematica 10.4

Tags: warning-messages, regular-expressions

There is a regular expression that I used often in *Mathematica* 8, made to locate matching curly braces:

```
RegularExpression["(?P<0>{([^{}]|(?P>0))*})"]
```

However, it is no longer working in *Mathematica* 10.4. It returns an error

```
RegularExpression::msg84: Group name must start with a non-digit [[etc.]]
```

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: Would you give us an example of how you use the RE you show fails. I do not find "to locate matching curly braces" sufficient to be able to reproduce the problem

Comment: I don't find that `RegularExpression["(?P<0>{([^{}]|(?P>0))*})"]` returns an error in my copy of 10.4 (Mac OS 10.10)

Comment: Replace the `0` in name with something with a non-digit initial...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fix the group name. Beats me why the change - first works in 9.X Win., but not on 10.3 Win...

```
StringPosition["{tes,{1,2,3},t}", RegularExpression["(?P<0>{([^{}]|(?P>0))*})"]]
```

> RegularExpression::msg84: Group name must start with a non-digit in RegularExpression[(?P<0>{([^{}]|(?P>0))*})]. >>

```
StringPosition["{tes,{1,2,3},t}", RegularExpression["(?P<grp0>{([^{}]|(?P>grp0))*})"]]
```

> {{1, 15}, {6, 12}}

Comment: PCRE used to allow names starting with digits.  But [version 8.34 of PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/original/changelog.txt) disallowed them -- to match the same change which was made in Perl.  It appears that _Mathematica_ 10.1 was the first release to use PCRE 8.34 or later.

Comment: @WReach - Thought as much, but did not want to shoot the mouth without knowing it to be true. Thanks for confirmation.